# Deep copy queue recursively C++ (Implemented using a doubly linked list)

Tags: c++, queue, doubly-linked-list, recursive-datastructures

I'm building a queue using a doubly linked list. I want my deep copy constructor to recursively deep copy the entire queue however I get a segmentation fault when I do the following:

```cpp
// Recursive helper method for deep copy constructor
void queue::copyAllNodes(Node* og, Node *cpy) {
    if(og == nullptr) back = og;
    else {
        cpy->previous = og->previous;
        cpy->data = og->data;
        cpy->next = og->next;
        copyAllNodes(og->next, cpy->next);
    }
}
```

my constructor has another helper function that allows me to pass in the original and the copy node i want to copy.

Comment: Most probably `cpy` would not have all the nodes allocated as required, take into account the creation of new nodes as well.

Comment: Seems unnecessary when you can just recycle the queue's push function.

Comment: Um... look at your code. Do you not see that the recursive call is effectively just `copyAllNodes(og->next, og->next);` due to the line immediately preceding it? Dare I ask what force on earth is possessing you to do a simple enumerate-and-copy task recursively rather than iterative in the first place? More often than not, recursion falls squarely in the zone of "just because you can doesn't mean you should".

Comment: I just want to see if i can do it, but it turns out its not as simple as I thought it was. I tried it without copying cpy->next but still seg fault

Comment: You never instantiate any new nodes, not sure where they are coming from, are there even any nodes you can copy to? Please show a [mre].

Comment: I agree with WhozCraig about _not_ using recursion. It's doesn't scale too well (e.g. suppose your list had 100,000,000 elements--would you get a stack overflow?). I'd start with a non-recursive function and get that working first [then, _if_ you _must_ a recursive solution]. You're using a `queue` member function but don't actually change it (e.g. `queue::push`). As it is, I think your solution needs refactoring even for the iterative case. Don't you need to allocate new nodes for the copy (e.g. `Node *dstnode = new Node(...);`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand you're not actually copying *anything* here. You're just enumerating by recursion and assigning pointers. At *best* that is a shallow copy; in reality your algorithm is completely broken. There *are* ways to copy a linked list recursively, including bidirectional linked lists. Whether it is wise to do so is another story.

---

**Unidirectional List**

Before getting into the subject of a bidirectional linked list, consider the base case of a unidirectional list. Suppose you have a linked list with nodes like this:

```
template<class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *next;

    Node(T dat, Node *nxt = nullptr)
        : data(std::move(dat))
        , next(nxt)
    {
    }
};
```

Now suppose you want to make a deep copy of this recursively. In its most simple form the algorithm for a recursive copy would be:

```
Node *copyDeep(const Node *p)
{
    Node *res = nullptr;
    if (p)
        res = new Node(p->data, copyDeep(p->next));
    return res;
}
```

---

**Bidirectional List**

Introducing a double-linked node (both `next` and `prev` members) makes this a bit more challenging, but not by much. First the node has to be modified to include the new member:

```
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;

    Node(T dat, Node *nxt = nullptr)
        : data(std::move(dat))
        , next(nxt)
        , prev(nullptr)
    {
    }
};
```

With that, `copyDeep` can be modified to remember the added node to be used as an added argument to the recursed call. One way of doing that is:

```
Node *copyDeep(Node *p, Node *prev = nullptr)
{
    if (p)
    {
        Node *res = new Node(p->data);
        res->prev = prev
        res->next = copyDeep(p->next, res);
        return res;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

---

In *both* cases it is easier, faster, and less error prone (including stack overflows) to do this iteratively. In answer to your question, yes you can recursively copy a linked list. Whether it's a good idea to do so I leave to you.